# Error when trying to create an User-Initiated object (ETEmailSendDefinition)

Tags: email, soap-api, marketing-cloud, java, error

I'm trying to use fuelsdk-0.999.jar and fuelsdk-0.9999.jar (both gave me the same error) in a Java projetc downloaded from https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Java/releases and when I try to call **post** method do create an **ETEmailSendDefinition** of **ETEmailSendDefinitionService**, it gives me the following error:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.AudienceItem.setDataSourceTypeID on   bean class 'class       com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.SendDefinitionList' - argument type   mismatch - had objects of type       "com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.model.ETDataSourceType" but expected       signature "com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.DataSourceTypeEnum"*

Look likes the code implemented in the server side is different of the code available in the fuel jar api. The code looks like this:

```
        ETSendDefinitionList sendDefinitionList = new ETSendDefinitionList();
        sendDefinitionList.setDataSourceTypeID(ETDataSourceType.LIST);
        sendDefinitionList.setIsTestObject(false);
        sendDefinitionList.setList(sendConfiguration.getMmList().getEtList()) ;
        sendDefinitionList.setSendDefinitionListType(ETSendDefinitionListType.SOURCE_LIST);

        List<ETSendDefinitionList> sendDefinitionListCollection = new ArrayList<ETSendDefinitionList>();
        sendDefinitionListCollection.add(sendDefinitionList);

        ETEmailSendDefinition emailSendDefinition = new ETEmailSendDefinition();
        emailSendDefinition.setName(sendConfiguration.getMmEmail().getName());
        emailSendDefinition.setCategoryID(1553);
        emailSendDefinition.setDescription(sendConfiguration.getMmEmail().getName());
        emailSendDefinition.setDynamicEmailSubject(sendConfiguration.getMmEmail().getEtEmail().getSubject());
        emailSendDefinition.setEmail(sendConfiguration.getMmEmail().getEtEmail());
        emailSendDefinition.setEmailSubject(sendConfiguration.getMmEmail().getEtEmail().getSubject());
        emailSendDefinition.setSendClassification(sendConfiguration.getMmSendClassification().getEtSendClassification());
        emailSendDefinition.setSendDefinitionList(sendDefinitionListCollection);

        ETEmailSendDefinitionService sendDefService = new ETEmailSendDefinitionServiceImpl();
        ETResponse<ETEmailSendDefinition> response = sendDefService.post(getETClientInstance(), emailSendDefinition);
```

Is this a bug or maybe a lack of updating the server side of FuelSDK? Can I use some kind of workaround to create and User-Initiated email?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a bug that has been fixed in version [0.99999](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Java/releases/tag/v0.99999). I have verified that the following code works in version 0.99999:

First, to create the user-initiated send definition (ETEmailSendDefinition):

```
ETClient client = new ETClient();

ETEmailSendDefinitionService service = new ETEmailSendDefinitionServiceImpl();

ETEmail email = new ETEmail();
email.setId(3202709); // email id (you can use customer key too)

ETSendDefinitionList sendDefinitionList = new ETSendDefinitionList();
ETList list = new ETList();
list.setId(1992264); // list id (you can use customer key too)
sendDefinitionList.setList(list);
sendDefinitionList.setDataSourceTypeID(ETDataSourceType.LIST);

List<ETSendDefinitionList> sendDefinitionLists = new ArrayList<ETSendDefinitionList>();
sendDefinitionLists.add(sendDefinitionList);

ETSendClassification sendClassification = new ETSendClassification();
sendClassification.setCustomerKey("13817"); // Default Commercial

ETEmailSendDefinition emailSendDefinition = new ETEmailSendDefinition();
emailSendDefinition.setName("test");
emailSendDefinition.setCustomerKey("test");
emailSendDefinition.setEmail(email);
emailSendDefinition.setSendClassification(sendClassification);
emailSendDefinition.setSendDefinitionList(sendDefinitionLists);

service.post(client, emailSendDefinition);
```

Then, to send the specified email to the specified list:

```
 ETClient client = new ETClient();

 ETEmailSendDefinitionService service = new ETEmailSendDefinitionServiceImpl();

 ETEmailSendDefinition emailSendDefinition = new ETEmailSendDefinition();
 emailSendDefinition.setCustomerKey("test");

 service.send(client, emailSendDefinition);
```

Let me know if this still isn't working for you.

-ian

Comment: Looks like this jar fixed the problem of different object types, but I still cannot send an email: now the response returns me an error of "Error, A send classification must be specified", even with a valid send classification and the response.getResults() shows a "null" object reference on send classification property. Can you check it too, please?

Comment: I have found additional issues related to object conversion. I am working on a fix and will have it posted by the end of the day today.

Comment: Update: I have not yet fully resolved this issue but continue to work on it. -ian

Comment: OK. We're currently trying to bypass "ET" classes of fuelsdk and using the "core" classes as a temporary solution (eg.: SendClassification instead of ETSendClassification), but it demands code that are already in ET classes.

Comment: Update: Thank you for your patience here. The fix required some refactoring which took time. I'm doing some testing today to ensure I didn't break anything and will have the fix posted by the end of the day (for real this time :-). -ian

Comment: Try this jar: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/496548/fuelsdk.jar. I have successfully created an EmailSendDefinition and performed a send on it using this code. Let me know if it works for you. I'll roll the next release tomorrow. -ian

Comment: Hi @ian. I've tried to use this new jar on the project, but there are some missing classes and other conflicts with our code (eg.: we are using ObjectConverter to convert ET classes to core classes). I notice that you also updated the git project and I guess that I have to use just ET classes from now on, but we are on a delivery and customer test phase has started and to change back the code to those new classes will require some time, so we are planing to do this refactor on the next week. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there some other channel that I can contact you? I'd like to ask some questions related to API but not concerned to this post!

Comment: You can now convert any external class to its internal representation via the toInternal method on the object (and vice versa with the fromInternal method). This replaces ObjectConverter. -ian

Comment: You can now convert any external class to its internal representation via the toInternal method on the object (and vice versa with the fromInternal method). This replaces ObjectConverter, which was an internal class (and thus I wasn't worried about backward compatibility). I have added a (deprecated) ObjectConverter wrapper class around toInternal() and fromInternal() that should solve your current issues. Can you try it out and let me know if it works for you? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/496548/fuelsdk.jar

Comment: Now when I try to call **ETDataExtensionColumnServiceImpl's** get method it returns this error:
The Request Property(s) ID do not match with the fields of DataExtensionField retrieve.

Looks like the **ETGetServiceImpl** class is getting this ID property on `retrieveRequest.getProperties().addAll(o.getProperties());` (line 101) and this property doesn't exists for the class it is using internally. Could you check, please?